# Comparing Class Types in Java

Tags: java, types, compare

I want to compare the class type in Java.

I thought I could do this:

```
class MyObject_1 {}
class MyObject_2 extends MyObject_1 {}

public boolean function(MyObject_1 obj) {
   if(obj.getClass() == MyObject_2.class) System.out.println("true");
}
```

I wanted to compare in case if the obj passed into the function was extended from MyObject_1 or not.
But this doesn't work. It seems like the getClass() method and the .class gives different type of information.

How can I compare two class type, without having to create another dummy object just to compare the class type?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
if(obj instanceof MyObject){System.out.println("true");} //true
```

Because of inheritance this is valid for interfaces, too:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}    

Dog obj = new Dog();
Animal animal = new Dog();
if(obj instanceof Animal){System.out.println("true");} //true
if(animal instanceof Animal){System.out.println("true");} //true
if(animal instanceof Dog){System.out.println("true");} //true
```

For further reading on instanceof: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/instanceof.html

Comment: But what happens if I want to check an Animal is an instance of Dog? Is it still possible?

Say:
public void check(Animal obj) {
if(obj instanceof Dog){System.out.println("true");} 
}

Is this still possible?

Comment: @xEnON: This is possible, but will always return false. You cannot check if an Interface is a instance of a concrete class.

Comment: So if I have function that makes use of this polymorphism feature, I cannot check its exact class type at runtime?

Comment: Sorry, it's wrong that this will always return false. Have not read your comment careful enough. See my answer.

Comment: Oh...I understand it is wrong and will return false. I was just thinking that if there is another way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 39):

If you don't want to or can't use `instanceof`, then compare with `equals`:

```
 if(obj.getClass().equals(MyObject.class)) System.out.println("true");
```

BTW - it's strange because the two `Class` instances in your statement really should be the same, at least in your example code. They *may* be different if:

- the classes have the same short name but are defined in different packages
- the classes have the same full name but are loaded by different classloaders.

Comment: I wonder why this answer has so many upvotes (I guess one of the reasons is that the question was changed after this answer was posted)? `java.lang.Class` does not override `Object.equals`, which means that for two non-null `cls1` and `cls2`: `cls1.equals(cls2)` is true if and only if `cls1 == cls2` is true. Which means that the proposed approach is the same that the topic starter described.

Answer (score 11):

It prints `true` on my machine. And it should, otherwise nothing in Java would work as expected. (This is explained in the JLS: [4.3.4 When Reference Types Are the Same](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3.4))

Do you have multiple classloaders in place?

---

Ah, and in response to this comment:

> I realise I have a typo in my
>   question. I should be like this:

```
MyImplementedObject obj = new MyImplementedObject ();
if(obj.getClass() == MyObjectInterface.class) System.out.println("true");
```

> MyImplementedObject implements
>   MyObjectInterface So in other words, I
>   am comparing it with its implemented
>   objects.

OK, if you want to check that you can do either:

```
if(MyObjectInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
```

or the much more concise

```
if(obj instanceof MyobjectInterface)
```

Comment: I realise I have a typo in my question. I should be like this:
MyImplementedObject obj = new MyImplementedObject ();
if(obj.getClass() == MyObjectInterface
.class) System.out.println("true");

MyImplementedObject implements MyObjectInterface


So in other words, I am comparing it with its implemented objects.

Comment: I have updated my post with the correct code I meant. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: thanks!! In your update, because obj is extended from MyObjectInterface, comparing obj with MyObjectInterface may be still ok. But what happens if I wanted to compare in the opposite direction. For instance, if obj is MyObject_1. And there is a MyObject_2 extended from MyObject_1. Then I wanted to check if obj is actually of MyObject_2 or not, would this still work? This is the update in my question post.

Answer (score 7):

As said earlier, your code will work unless you have the same classes loaded on two different class loaders.
This might happen in case you need multiple versions of the same class in memory at the same time, or you are doing some weird on the fly compilation stuff (as I am).

In this case, if you want to consider these as the same class (which might be reasonable depending on the case), you can match their names to compare them.

```
public static boolean areClassesQuiteTheSame(Class<?> c1, Class<?> c2) {
  // TODO handle nulls maybe?
  return c1.getCanonicalName().equals(c2.getCanonicalName());
}
```

Keep in mind that this comparison will do just what it does: compare class names; I don't think you will be able to cast from one version of a class to the other, and before looking into reflection, you might want to make sure there's a good reason for your classloader mess.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing an object with a class using `instanceOf` or ... is already answered.

If you have two objects and you want to compare their types with **each other**, you can use:

```java
if (obj1.getClass() == obj2.getClass()) {
   // Both have the same type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had two Strings and compared them using == by calling the getClass() method on them, it would return true. What you get is a reference on the same object.

This is because they are both references on the same class object. This is true for all classes in a java application.
Java only loads the class once, so you have only one instance of a given class at a given time.

```
String hello  = "Hello";
String world = "world";

if (hello.getClass() == world.getClass()) {
    System.out.println("true");
} // prints true
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... Keep in mind that Class may or may not implement equals() -- that is not required by the spec. For instance, HP Fortify will flag myClass.equals(myOtherClass).

Answer (score -2):

Check `Class.java` source code for `equals()`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return this == obj;
}
```