# How to compare if one object is the same type as another

Tags: java

In the list below there are 3 trucks and I need to add up how many are trailers with example.

In the first 'if' I am wanting to compare if the vehicle is of the same type as a truck, but with the 'equals', this code is not printing anything and the certainty was that it should print 3.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class TesteTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    vehicles.add(new Car());
    vehicles.add(new Car());
    vehicles.add(new Truck());
    vehicles.add(new Truck());
    vehicles.add(new Truck());

    int counter = 0;
    Truck truck = new Truck();
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
        System.out.println();
        if (vehicle.equals(truck)) {
            truck = (Truck) vehicle;
            if (truck.hasTruck()) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

How can I compare without rewriting the equal method?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use instanceOf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149677/comparing-class-types-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing Class Types in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149677/comparing-class-types-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these methods other than instanceOf method

```
Object.getClass() returns runtime type of object
```

In your code sample if statement can be used in this way

```
if (vehicle.getClass() == Truck.class)
```

OR

```
if (Truck.class.isInstance(vehicle))
```

OR

```
try {
    Truck truck = (Truck) vehicle;
    // No exception: obj is of type Truck or IT MIGHT BE NULL!
   //here null value will also be type casted if present
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
}
```

Considering the good object oriented design the instanceOf, getClass, isInstance methods should never be used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

The equals method uses the hash method of the object to compare.

Look this: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/

The simplest way to do this is by using the [instanceof operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList();
    vehicles.add(new Car());
    vehicles.add(new Car());
    vehicles.add(new Truck());
    vehicles.add(new Truck());
    vehicles.add(new Truck());

    int counter = 0;
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
        if (vehicle instanceof Truck) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```