# Check which class

Tags: java, oop

I have an object of a child class and an array of the parent class that stores objects of the child classes in it.

```
mafia[] obj = new mafia[no_mafia];
detective[] obj1 = new detective[no_detectives];
healer[] obj2 = new healer[no_healers];
commoner[] obj3 = new commoner[no_commoners];
```

the parent class is called player and basically stores each individual objects of each of its child class in it

```
alive_players[0] = obj[0];//just an example
```

Now I want to check if the classes of each of their objects are the same for eg:

```
obj[0].equals(alive_players[rand_var]);
```

But this doesn't seem to work as they're all subclasses of the class player(which is the parent class). How exactly will I be able to differentiate between their classes? And is there a better way to store all the objects of the subclasses in a common place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing Class Types in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149677/comparing-class-types-in-java)

Comment: I get that using instanceof would probably work but is there anyway I could override the equals function in my child class and then try comparing?

Comment: Purpose of equals is to compare objects, not their classes. You can of course override equals any way you want.

Comment: Why not put the different types of players into different collections?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Java instanceof](https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator): The java instanceof operator is used to test whether the object is an instance of the specified type

Comment: is there any way I could override the equals function in the class and try it out?

Comment: Sure. It would render equals useless for its real purpose (comparing instances of objects), but you do you.